# Add Bootstrap Carousel to Region

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I am creating a custom front page (using a template page--front.tpl.php).

I've defined a few regions to be used on my front page. In one of these regions I would like to embed a Bootstrap Carousel (that was created with the [Bootstrap Carousel](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap_carousel) module). Can this be done? It appears only `block`s can be added. A Carousel appears to be of type `content`. Perhaps this can be done using Views or a similar module?

The reason for me going this route is for simplicity of updating the carousel. Another maintainer of this website does not have PHP/HTML/CSS skills, so I would like for them to simple update the carousel using the Drupal admin interface, as opposed to updating page--front.tpl.php itself.

Comment: Try to google for "drupal node as block", it usually gives a lot of relevant results. Also, views may be a good call, too. So try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar and used the [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) Module. I am not sure if you are using also a Bootstrap Subtheme, but  here is what i did:

1. Installed the [Bootstrap Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) and created a Subtheme.
2. Installed [JQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update). (Most recent Bootstrap need JQuery 1.9)
3. Installed [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap).
4. Created a Views Block for my Slides. I did it with articles which have an imagegallery field.
5. Added a contextual filter, so for each article a carousel of images can be added in form of a block.
6. In the Views Block under Format i choosed Bootstrap Carousel.

[image]

Then i had a Carousel Block to put in any region i want. You can configure your view to serve your personal needs.

Comment: Is this mandatory to use Bootstrap theme to achieve this. Because i tried the same thing with different theme, but its not working. Please help me in this regard.